# Организация бд

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть список с продуктами. У каждого продукта есть список параметров, примерно до десяти у каждого. Уникальных параметров может быть десятки тысяч. Необходимо вывести группы товаров, в которых два и более параметра совпали. В качестве бд использую postgresql (массивы и прочие плюшки). Помогите придумать, как лучше организовать для данной задачи таблицы.

Comment: Совпали параметры или значение параметров?

Comment: @Ale_x, параметры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе подойдет [этот](http://www.askdev.ru/sql/828/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5/#answer1683) пример с тегами.

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  post AS p,
  post_tag AS pt
WHERE
  p.id = pt.post_id
  AND pt.tag_id IN (SELECT
                tag_id
              FROM
                post_tag
              WHERE
                post_id = 1
              )
  AND p.id != 1
GROUP BY
  p.id
```

Comment: хм...) у вас в вопросе то стоит задача ГРУППИРОВКИ , а не сравнения одного продукта с другими по количеству параметров.

Answer (score 0):

Сильно ли отличаются запросы в postgresql от mysql?

Вчера накидал вариант, немного криво написано, но работает.

Посмотрите http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f02ad7/1

Суть проста - делаем таблицу продуктов, таблицу параметров и еще одну перекрестную таблицу для связи параметров с продуктами. Затем при выборке находим в перекрестной таблице те продукты, у которых 2 и более параметров совпадают. При желании можно расширить результат JOINами, чтобы вывести название продуктов и параметров.

Вот такой "страшный" запрос получается:

```
SELECT s.aa as 'first product', s.bb as 'second product', count(s.param_id) as 'Count of common parameters' FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT a.product_id as aa, b.product_id as bb, a.param_id
    FROM products_x_params a, products_x_params b
    WHERE
      a.param_id = b.param_id
    AND
      a.id < b.id
  ) s
group by s.aa,s.bb HAVING (count(s.param_id)>1)
ORDER BY s.aa, s.bb, s.param_id
```